# Delphi смещение указателя

Tags: c#, delphi, память

Переписываю программу на C# и столкнулся с проблемой, никак не пойму как происходит работа с памятью, может кто нибудь объяснить или помочь переписать кусочек, на вход подается бинарник, потом записывается в **Psh**

```
massiv = array [1..9000] of word;
mkts = array [0..3, 1..6, 1..16] of SmallInt;
mdl = array [0..3, 1..6, 1..15] of SmallInt;
msh = array[1..392] of SmallInt;

TPmkts = ^mkts;
TPmdl = ^mdl;
TPmsh = ^msh;

Pkts: array[1..4, 1..2] of TPmkts = ( (nil, nil),
                                (nil, nil), (nil, nil), (nil, nil) );
Pdl: array[1..4, 1..2] of TPmdl = ( (nil, nil),
                                (nil, nil), (nil, nil), (nil, nil) );
Psh: array[1..4, 1..2] of TPmsh = ( (nil, nil),
                                (nil, nil), (nil, nil), (nil, nil) );
begin
...
New(Pdl[1, 1]);
New(Pozu[1, 1]);
Pkts[1, 1]:= @Psh[1, 1]^[9];

for KCO:=0 to 3 do
for Tip:=1 to 6 do
begin
  CCO:=1;
  repeat
    if PKTS[1, 1]^[KCO, Tip, CCO] = (-1) then
      PDL[1, 1]^[KCO, Tip, CCO]:= 0
    else
    begin
      i:=CCO;
      repeat Inc(i);
      until (PKTS[1, 1]^[KCO, Tip, i] <> (-1));
      PDL[1, 1]^[KCO, Tip, CCO]:= PKTS[1, 1]^[KCO, Tip, i] -
                                         PKTS[1, 1]^[KCO, Tip, CCO];
      case Tip of
       2,5  : PDL[1, 1]^[KCO, Tip, CCO]:=
                                     PDL[1, 1]^[KCO, Tip, CCO]*5;
       3,4,6: PDL[1, 1]^[KCO, Tip, CCO]:=
                                     PDL[1, 1]^[KCO, Tip, CCO]*8;
      end; 
    end;
    Inc(CCO);
  until CCO=16;
end;
..
end
```

Comment: В c# нет указателей. Чтобы в принципе не возникало ошибок, связанных с ними. Непосредственно с памятью программист вообще не работает.

Comment: @Sergey я думаю, если понять принцип работы с памятью, то можно будет написать аналогию используя BinaryReader

Comment: В c# в Вашем распоряжении объекты разных видов, массивы. Сделайте себе этих объектов каких надо. Получайте данные с помощью BinaryReader и раскладывайте по полям/свойствам объектов, по массивам и спискам как надо. Единственно смещение - это индекс в массиве.

Comment: @Sergey Спасибо, но я в курсе. Трабл с алгоритмом, в бинарнике определенная последовательность, вот ее я и хочу узнать.

Comment: Кажется Ваш пример не так уж сложно переделать без указателей. Вижу только указатели на массивы. Даже смещений вроде нет. Просто элемент одного массива является указателем на другой. Элементарно же переделывается.

Comment: @Sergey если Вам не сложно, то я бы не отказался от Вашей помощи, даже если код будет на Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Только общий подход на частных примерах
Имеем:

```
massiv = array [1..9000] of word;
mkts = array [0..3, 1..6, 1..16] of SmallInt;
mdl = array [0..3, 1..6, 1..15] of SmallInt;
msh = array[1..392] of SmallInt;

TPmkts = ^mkts;
TPmdl = ^mdl;
TPmsh = ^msh;

Pkts: array[1..4, 1..2] of TPmkts = ( (nil, nil),
                            (nil, nil), (nil, nil), (nil, nil) );
Pdl: array[1..4, 1..2] of TPmdl = ( (nil, nil),
                            (nil, nil), (nil, nil), (nil, nil) );
Psh: array[1..4, 1..2] of TPmsh = ( (nil, nil),
                            (nil, nil), (nil, nil), (nil, nil) );
```

Получаем:

```
// pkts - двумерный массив, элементами которого являются трехмерные массивы
int[,][,,] pkts = new int[4,2][,,];

// аналогично pdl - двумерный массив, элементами которого являются трехмерные массивы
// пример с инициализацией (поскольку всё и так null - необязательной)
int[,][,,] pdl = new int[4,2][,,] {
    {null, null}, {null, null}, {null, null}, {null, null}
};

// psh - двумерный массив, элементами которого являются одномерные массивы
int[,][] psh = new int[4,2][];

// PKTS[1, 1]^[KCO, Tip, CCO] становится 
pkts[0, 0][KCO - 1, Tip - 1, CCO - 1]

// PDL[1, 1]^[KCO, Tip, CCO] становится 
pdl[0, 0][KCO - 1, Tip - 1, CCO - 1]

// PSH[i, j]^[k] становится
psh[i - 1, j - 1][k - 1]

// Инициализация New(PDL[1, 1]) превращается в 
pdl[0, 0] = new int[4, 6, 15];
// размерности нового массива берём из объявления mdl = array [0..3, 1..6, 1..15] of SmallInt;

// Какой-нибудь New(PKTS[i, j]) превращается в
pkts[i - 1, j - 1] = new int[4, 6, 16];

// Как же переделать Pkts[1, 1]:= @Psh[1, 1]^[9];?
// Тут манипуляции с указателем, которые просто так не перенести
pkts[0, 0] = psh[0, 0][8]; // ошибка
// надо что-то придумывать, исходя из конкретной задачи.
// наверняка там в Psh какая-то структура. Типа заголовок в 9 элементов,
// а далее трехмерный массив, годный для pkts
// разумнее psh представить в виде объекта, в котором явно выделяются 
// составные части.
// Или нужную часть массива подручными средствами переносить в требуемый
// трехмерный
```

**Индексы и размерности подгоняются с учётом того, что в c# индексы начинаются с нуля!**

**Внимательнее надо быть с такими штуками как Pkts[1, 1]:= @Psh[1, 1]^[9];**
См. комментарий в коде выше

Надеюсь не сильно ошибся, допустив что в c# есть многомерные jagged-массивы. Прямого упоминания этого не встречал. Но раз говорится об одномерных jagged, то логично предположить наличие многомерных.

Comment: Многомерные Jagged массивы есть, вы не ошиблись. А не лучше будет аккуратно разложить по полочкам в одном ответе?

Comment: @rdorn Может быть и лучше, но редактирование на сайте не располагает к длинным текстам.

Answer (score 2):

```
Pkts[1, 1]:= @Psh[1, 1]^[9];
```

Это говорит о наличии какой-то структуры в массиве байтов. В дельфи логично было бы изобразить так:

```
TPhs = record (
    head: array [1..8] of integer;
    data: array [0..3, 1..6, 1..16] of integer;
);
```

В c# практически аналогично

```
class TPsh {
    public int[8] head;
    public int[4, 6, 16] data;
}
```

Тогда

```
ptsk[0, 0] = psh[0, 0].data;
```

Где psh является таким массивом

```
TPsh[,] psh = new TPsh[4, 2];
```

Инициализация элемента

```
psh[i, j] = new TPsh();
```

Но есть разница в загрузке данных из потока в структуру паскаля и c#.
В паскале можно загрузить за один раз, в c# придётся загружать отдельно head и отдельно data.